# main(): Failed opening required 'core/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add files to my route, which will be used in my application and the file paths are

```
base_path().'/public/assets/global/plugins/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php';
base_path().'/public/assets/global/plugins/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php';
```

I created two routes for in **routes.php**:

```
Route::get('kcfinder/browse.php', function()
            {
                include base_path().'/public/assets/global/plugins/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php';
            });
            Route::get('kcfinder/upload.php', function()
            {
                include base_path().'/public/assets/global/plugins/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php';
            });
```

After doing this i am getting this error:

[image]

Where do i have to setup the autoload file? It says core/autoload.php which i can not find.

Any suggestions? How can i resolve the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: What you have written in both files that you are including?

Comment: In laravel route you should call a controller function or return something(string  or objects or anything.)

Comment: Just try to return some text in browse.php or upload.php and check its working or not ?

Comment: @LearningMode they are the file from kcfinder (filebrowser plugin for ckeditor)/

Comment: Yes its returning the the text properly

Comment: I guess its just about autoload i am not able to get that file

Comment: You should load view  in route and include your file in view.

Comment: Also dont use .php in route . Although it will work but its not good practice. At least in laravel